# Cannot access variable in Javascript array. Console.log says undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I have an object which contains an array that I then pass to another function in order for that function to use. The only thing is, when I go to access these variables, console.log says they are undefined. It's strange as when I log the whole array it ways the values are there but when I go to access the array element specifically, it returns undefined.
Here is my code:

```
googleMapsFunctions.prototype.calculateDistances = function() {
        var that = this;    
        console.log(that.latLngArray);
        var closeClubs = [];
        var sortable = [];
        var resultsArray = [];
        jQuery(this.clubs).each(function(key, club) {
            var clubLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(club.latitude, club.longitude);         
            var distanceFromLoc = clubLatLng.distanceFrom(that, "", "");        
            //alert(distanceFromLoc);
            //that.clubs[key].distance = distanceFromLoc;
            //closeClubs.push(club);
        });
        closeClubs.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.distance - b.distance;
        });

    }

googleMapsFunctions.prototype.setLatLng = function() {
        var that = this;
        this.geocoder.geocode({'address' : this.location}, function(results, status) {
            if(status === "OK") {                   
                that.latLngArray.push(parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat()));
                that.latLngArray.push(parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng()));                  
            }               
        });
    }
```

//Client Code

```
var googleMapsClass = new googleMapsFunctions(JSONItems, searchTerm);
    googleMapsClass.setLatLng();        
    googleMapsClass.calculateDistances();
```

I am using console.log to print out the array (that.latLngArray) which gives the following:

[image]

I then click on the aray brackets and it takes me to the following (which is the correct information).

[image]

I just can't seem to access these variables and it says that they are undefined.
Can anyone see what is happening here?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear from the code you posted, but it's most likely a problem involving code that expects an asynchronous operation to complete synchronously.

Comment: There is a Google maps geocode being called too. I'll add it to the code example.

Comment: Right, well there you go. The call to "setLatLng" will return immediately after *initiating* (but not *completing*) the Google API call.

Comment: Ah yeah I see. Is there anyway round this?

Comment: You can use a Promise mechanism or else you can do the distance calculations in the callback to the geocode thing. [Here is a lovely explanation of the simple yet super-handy Promise idea.](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: I can't really get my head around it to be honest. Is there any chance you could give me a hand in how you would apply this to my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing to do would be to just move the distance calculation inside the callback:

```
googleMapsFunctions.prototype.setLatLng = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.geocoder.geocode({'address' : this.location}, function(results, status) {
        if(status === "OK") {                   
            that.latLngArray.push(parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat()));
            that.latLngArray.push(parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng()));
            // now it's safe to check the distances
            that.calculateDistances();
        }               
    });
}
```